# Migrating only a subset of Flyway migrations

Tags: java, flyway

How to force Flyway to only apply a subset of the migrations and ignore the rest using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Callbacks](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks) are handy but can't stop a migration from happening.

You need to implement [MigrationResolver and MigrationExecutor](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/hooks#callsbacks) in order to catch certain situations.

I must say though, this sounds like a precarious solution to implement for the sake of repeatable schema evolution. Perhaps you could elaborate on the situation that requires you to do this.